# Jena SDB default encoding

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, uri, urlencode, jena

I have some IRIs containing German and French characters like:

```
http://example.org/text/Citroën
```

and I want to insert them into Jena SDB. The default MySQL database charset is latin1. Should I change the encoding to UTF8? What if the IRI contains Chinese or Japanese characters, should I change it UTF8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if the database (and JDBC connection) is UTF8.  If it is, you don't have to worry later other language data and the JDBC connection is UTF8.  If you must run latin1, then in the JDBC URL, declare it to be UTF8 (see MySQL doc for details).